A movie in which a statue of woman dressed in black moves and kills at night
I watched this movie about 15-20 years ago, I can't remember correctly. There was a scene in which this statue of woman dressed in black is moved into some museum or building and then moves around and kills people.
I probably saw it on HBO or Star Movies around 2005. Initially I thought it was some Mummy franchise movie. I was so young then. Later I searched all the Mummy movies and nothing showed up.

Can you describe that woman and her dress?

Not remember that much, but i think it's some gown or something fully covered  including her face. And she was not walking. It's like she was flowing through the floor. And disappears suddenly.

Belphegor _ 2001 movie

Got it..... Belphegor, Phantom of the Louvre from 2001

A rare collection of artifacts from an archeological dig in Egypt are brought to the famous Musée du Louvre in Paris. While experts are using a laser scanning device to determine the age of a sarcophagus, a spirit escapes and makes its way into the museum's electrical system. Museum curator Faussier (Jean-Francois Balmer) brings in noted Egyptologist, Glenda Spencer (Julie Christie), to examine the findings, and she announces that the mummy inside the coffin was actually the evil spirit Belphegor.
Meanwhile, Lisa (Sophie Marceau), a young woman who lives across the street from the museum, follows her runaway cat into the Louvre after closing time. She accidentally receives an electrical shock that transfers the stray spirit into her body. Soon Lisa is disguising herself as Belphegor and making off with the rare Egyptian treasures on display at the museum, convinced that they are rightfully hers. When Belphegor proves more than a match for the Louvre's security forces, renowned detective Verlac (Michel Serrault) is brought out of retirement to find out why the museum's Egyptian collection has been shrinking.

Trailer




Hi!  You could improve this answer (and earn more reputation) by including a brief description or synopsis of the movie, noting how it matches the question and any details in the question you may have gotten wrong.

I added a quick summary from the Wikipedia article. You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
